# Adding custom layout to Omega child theme breaks grid system

Tags: theming

I'm trying to create an new responsive layout in an Omega child theme. To do this I copied the `grids` variable from alpha.info into MYTHEME.info and added my layout (called 'narrower') based on the existing pattern:

```
grids[alpha_default][name] = Default (960px)
grids[alpha_default][layouts][fluid] = Fluid
grids[alpha_default][layouts][narrower] = Narrower
grids[alpha_default][layouts][narrow] = Narrow
grids[alpha_default][layouts][normal] = Normal
grids[alpha_default][layouts][wide] = Wide
grids[alpha_default][columns][12] = 12 Columns
grids[alpha_default][columns][16] = 16 Columns
grids[alpha_default][columns][24] = 24 Columns

settings[alpha_layouts_alpha_default_narrower_responsive] = '1'
settings[alpha_layouts_alpha_default_narrower_media] = 'all and (min-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 480px), (max-device-width: 740px) and (min-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape)'
settings[alpha_layouts_alpha_default_narrower_weight] = '0'
```

I also added a css file: MYTHEME-alpha-default-narrower.css

The problem I'm seeing is that none of the omega/alpha grid system css files are loaded (e.g. `sites/all/themes/omega/alpha/css/grid/alpha_default/wide/alpha-default-wide-12.css`)

Apparently others have had success with this (like here: [How to add a new responsive Layout for large viewports to Omega Theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/how-to-add-a-new-responsive-layout-for-large-viewports-to-omega-theme)), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.